# make class with QTimer in thread

Tags: qt, qthread, qtimer

I need a class that sends data from another thread by timer
like this:

```
QPointer<Checker> checker;
connect(checker, &Checker::newData, this, &MyClass::process, Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection); // process(QMap<QString, int>)
```

My realization: .h

```
class Checker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread m_thread;
    QTimer m_timer;
signals:
    void stop();
private slots:
    void started() { m_timer.start(1000); }
    void stoped() { m_timer.stop(); }
    void timeout();
public:
    Checker();
    ~Checker();
    Q_SIGNAL void newData(QMap<QString, int>);
};
```

.cpp

```
void Checker::timeout()
{
    emit newData({});
}

Checker::Checker()
{
    this->moveToThread(&m_thread);

    m_timer.moveToThread(&m_thread);
    m_thread.start();

    connect(&m_thread, &QThread::started, this, &Checker::started);
    connect(this, &Checker::stop, this, &Checker::stoped);
    connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Checker::timeout);
}

Checker::~Checker()
{
    emit stop();
    m_thread.quit();
    m_thread.wait();
}
```

Is this code correct?
Is there an easier way?
Why QueuedConnection don't connect? (BlockingQueuedConnection - worked)

Comment: you should first connect and then start the thread. This way the signal is not emitted and the timer is not started!
Furthermore, in my experience you don't really need to the set the type of connection (Queued/Blocked) since Qt does a decent job on that

Comment: ok, thanks. I fix it, but code was working.

Comment: Why connect to MyClass with QueuedConnection succesfull, but don't work? with Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection - work.

Comment: You might be getting a message during runtime that says `QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type`. You need to register that type in order for the queued connection to work.

Comment: thanks, I get this error.

Comment: In test project all ok. In work project, show :Cannot queue arguments of type 'QMap<QString,Data>'
`struct Data { int a,b };`
Possible problem is in 'namespace'

Comment: You have to use [`qRegisterMetaType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType).

Comment: yes, I used, but problem not solved. register type call before connect
`qRegisterMetaType< DATA_MAP >()`

Comment: Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( DATA_MAP )  was also added